# Can this SQL cause unclosed quotation mark?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I've been tracking a bug in how single quotes/apostrohpes are handled in an application, and I've found a suspect in a database trigger.

That trigger contains code like this: (shortened and anonymized)

```
insert into logTable ([NewRowData]) 
select 
  (select isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), [Foo]),'NULL') as Foo 
   from inserted i where  i.MyID = u.PrsID for xml raw('NewRowData')) 
from @updated_row u
```

In production, I get errors when "Foo" contains a single quote, (For example "O'Hara")

> Incorrect syntax near 'Hara'. Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ',NULL)'.

However, I cannot replicate this. A manual insert/update that fires the trigger does not give an error.

Is is possible that the nested functions isnull and convert somehow messes up quotation escapes or am I looking in the wrong direction?

(Cannot find any dynamic SQL genereation anywhere, which naturally was my first suspicion.)

Database is SQL server 2012.

Addendum:
I did a similar test to what Vérace posted below before posting here with the same result i.e no exception. If there IS a bug, it must be dependant on database version, settings or query execution plan.

Comment: Where is @updated_row being populated? That isn't a valid trigger as it stands

Comment: @MisterMagoo, that got lost in shortening. updated_row is a table variable containing keys from deleted and inserted.

Comment: Nothing to do with the XML bits? I'm not an expert on SQL Server but could the error be in there?

Comment: What is your application? You can think "there is no dynamic SQL in there" but it still can be. For example, SSRS executes your plain queries by calling sp_executesql, and there is an issue with a single quote. Why don't you use Profiler to catch the code passed to server?

Comment: Where are you capturing the error?

Comment: The application is a legacy Behemoth. My only lead is that error message. However, since capital "NULL" doesn't occur anywhere else in the code base near the "foo". The data access layer uses Entity Framework (which in turn uses sp_executeSql, I know) and I cannot provoke an error there.

Comment: So, it's a [Behemoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth)! Is it also a [Juggernaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggernaut)? Been there, done that! :-). As I said, not a SQL Server expert, but is there a facility to log **all** queries sent to the server? Maybe you could do this on your test system and then examine the actual SQL text that the server is trying to execute? It's what I would do with other servers!

Comment: Sorry to butt in again, but I'm looking at that code. The ISNULL does, well, err... nothing. SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), name), NULL) AS Foo FROM test does the exact same thing as SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), name) AS Foo FROM test; Will update answer!

Comment: @Vérace Actually, the ISNULL replaces null values with a literal sting 'NULL'. (Don't ask me why though, might be because of some xml schema or just cargo cult...)

Comment: Wow! Wierd! I just thought that the string thing was some sort of MySQL-type relic from bygone days of yore - e.g. in MySQL, you can insert '1' as the number one in a INTEGER field. But, as I said, SQL Server is not my forte! Will edit!

Comment: First of all is this an sql problem? Is your table set up correctly and has the xml been imported successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - it is **NOT** your SQL!

To answer this, I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  num INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Paoul');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'O''Hara');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, NULL);
```

then,

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

gives:

```
num     name
___     _____
1       Paoul
2       Mary
3       O'Hara
4       (null)
```

And then ran:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), name), 'NULL') AS Foo FROM test;
```

And got the result:

```
Foo
____
Paoul
Mary
O'Hara
NULL        <----- String literal, not the value NULL!
```

Which is what you'd expect! Quite why one would want to insert the string literal `NULL` is beyond me - Hmm... Developers: "three-value logic, my head is melted - I'll just stick in the string and we can do an `OR`!". Or, was this system in Oracle at one point? Empty string and NULL string being the same thing?

So, whatever your problem is, it is not your SQL as shown above causing this problem! Check the SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd96b/10) (note: using MS SQL Server 2014!).

As for your point about it being a version bug - I find it difficult to believe that such a basic functionality would be buggy in a 2012 Server version. Such a bug would have broken loads of legacy code!

My hunch is that the problem lies somewhere with the XML part of the code and the bits we can't see. I would set up logging (of all queries) and check out the SQL text that is actually being sent to the server (on my test system).

Comment: @Vérace I'm accepting this as the answer, since I cannot replicate the error even after several variants. Perhaps someone else fixed this earlier, without closing the bug? Who knows. It's not critical to the application, and if it wasn't for the smell of sql injection vulnerability, I'd have dropped it long ago.

Comment: Thanks for that! Just as a matter of interest and out of pure curiosity, was there anything in the guess that the system was on Oracle at one time?